# Variable width selection buttons on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nsarray

I'm trying to achieve this but not really sure where to start; would be great if I could be pointed in the right direction:

[image]

The 'interests' would simply be an array of items and I would like to display them like shown above as varied-width rounded buttons.

Comment: You should be able to do this with a collection view.

Comment: I have the same problem , do you solve it ?

Answer (score -2):

Your doubt is not entirely clear. If you are asking how to create buttons of variable width according to their text content, you can try the following :

```
- (UIButton *)setupVariableWidthButton{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    button.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    CGSize contstrainedSize = CGSizeMake(200, 40);//The maximum width and height 

    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0], NSFontAttributeName,
                                          nil];
    NSString *labelText = @"Long text";

//Calculate the required width and height just enough to show the text
    CGRect frame = [labelText boundingRectWithSize:contstrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributesDictionary context:nil];

//Set the frame of the button using the calculated required size
    button.frame = CGRectMake(5, 40, CGRectGetWidth(frame)+5, CGRectGetHeight(frame));
    [button setTitle:labelText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    return button;
}
```